# In pandas, how do I create a new column that captures a 0 or 1 value as a list of strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got this data frame. The columns look off but they are ['filename', 'diabetic retinopathy', 'glaucoma', 'others'].

```
filename        diabetic retinopathy    glaucoma    others
0   c24a1b14d253.jpg    0   1   1
1   9ee905a41651.jpg    0   0   1
2   3f58d128caf6.jpg    0   1   0
3   4ce6599e7b20.jpg    0   0   1
4   0def470360e4.jpg    0   0   1
```

I would like to create a new column called 'labels' that has lists of strings as its values. For example the entry associated with the first image file (row 0) would be:
['glaucoma', 'others'].

ultimately Id like to have a new df thats just 'filename' and 'labels'.
I'm new to pandas, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have 5 column names but only 4 values per row in your example?

Comment: @not_speshal. 'diabetic retinopathy' is a same name

Answer (score 1):

Try with `apply`:

```
df["label"] = df.apply(lambda row: df.columns[row.eq(1)].tolist(), axis=1)

>>> df[["filename", "label"]]

           filename               label
0  c24a1b14d253.jpg  [glaucoma, others]
1  9ee905a41651.jpg            [others]
2  3f58d128caf6.jpg          [glaucoma]
3  4ce6599e7b20.jpg            [others]
4  0def470360e4.jpg            [others]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorial solution using `melt`, `loc`, and `groupby`+`agg`:

```
(df.melt(id_vars='filename', var_name='labels')
   .loc[lambda d: d['value'].eq(1)]
   .groupby('filename')
   .agg({'labels': ','.join})  # use list instead of ','.join to have lists
   .reset_index()
)
```

While it seems this solution involves more computations that the `apply` method, it is actually much faster (more that 100 times faster on 10k rows: `1.17 s ± 75 ms` for apply vs `8.51 ms ± 370 µs` for the vectorial pipeline)

output:

```
           filename           labels
0  0def470360e4.jpg           others
1  3f58d128caf6.jpg         glaucoma
2  4ce6599e7b20.jpg           others
3  9ee905a41651.jpg           others
4  c24a1b14d253.jpg  glaucoma,others
```

Comment: OK. I had the same idea. I remove my answer to avoid duplicated

Comment: @Corralien don't feel like you have to

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pandas matrix multiplication [`.dot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) function on the second columns onwards to create the new column `label`, as follows:

```
df['labels'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].dot(df.columns[1:] + ',').str[:-1].str.split(',')
```

If your dataset is large and performance is a major concern, you can use list comprehension, as follows:

```
df['labels'] = [df.columns[1:][x].tolist() for x in df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(1).values]
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

           filename  diabetic retinopathy  glaucoma  others              labels
0  c24a1b14d253.jpg                     0         1       1  [glaucoma, others]
1  9ee905a41651.jpg                     0         0       1            [others]
2  3f58d128caf6.jpg                     0         1       0          [glaucoma]
3  4ce6599e7b20.jpg                     0         0       1            [others]
4  0def470360e4.jpg                     0         0       1            [others]
```

For further creating the new df that just have `filename` and `labels` columns, you can use:

```
new_df = df[['filename', 'labels']]
```

**Result:**

```
print(new_df)

           filename              labels
0  c24a1b14d253.jpg  [glaucoma, others]
1  9ee905a41651.jpg            [others]
2  3f58d128caf6.jpg          [glaucoma]
3  4ce6599e7b20.jpg            [others]
4  0def470360e4.jpg            [others]
```